# Beginner JavaFX, tracking a max radius generated randomly?

Tags: java, random, javafx, max

I have a project where I have to fill a 600x400 window (JavaFX) with 30 random sized circles with no filling. The largest circle must be filled with a translucent red (and if there are multiple large circles with the same radius only one can be filled). I'm able to get all the circles on the screen fine. My problem is getting the largest circle to be red. I haven't been taught arrays which were used in almost all of my many google searches. I cant figure out how exactly to track the largest circle. His hint to us is : "When it comes to keeping track of the largest circle, remember that two reference variables can point to the same Circle object. Maintain a separate Circle reference variable that always points to the largest circle (so far created). You may want to initialize this variable to a circle that has a radius of 0. You can get the radius of a circle using the getRadius method." I created a circle object and a largestCircle object but don't understand how to make the largestCircle object have the highest radius.

This is the code I have so far:

```
    {
    Random gen = new Random();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int radius = 0;
    double largestRadius = Math.max(radius);
    Circle largestCircle = null;
    Group root = new Group();
    //prints out 30 circles
    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, radius);

        {
            radius = gen.nextInt(66) + 10; //generates random radius from 10 to 75
            x = gen.nextInt(600 - 2 * radius) + radius;
            y = gen.nextInt(400 - 2 * radius) + radius;
        }

        if (circle.getRadius() == largestRadius)
        {
            largestCircle = circle;
            largestCircle.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.3));
        }

        circle.setFill(null);
        circle.setStroke(Color.rgb(gen.nextInt(256), + gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256)));
        circle.setStrokeWidth(3);
        root.getChildren().add(circle);
    }
```

after I generate the random circles how to I find the max radius that was generated and set it to largestCircle? the highest radius a circle can be is 75, but sometimes none of the circles have a radius of 75. How do I set the max to be the highest number the program randomly generates?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time

Comment: Seems like you only need one more conditional statement to me. You are correctly setting the largestCircle when the radius' are equal, but not when the `circle` radius is larger than the `largestRadius`

Comment: Huh! `double largestRadius = Math.max(radius);` Do yourself a favour and get it to a state in which everything compiles, even if doesn't do what you expect it to do. Afterwards, you can debug through it and see what is wrong and why doesn't it do what you expect from it.

Comment: i feel as though my: double largestRadius = Math.max(radius); is incorrect. I just don't know of any other way to find the largestRadius other then to use the Math.Max() method. but in order to use that method i need to compare two parameters when really i just want to test the radius. how do I get the largest radius from the random generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following.

It has a two fixes.
-1, use `>` and not `==` when figuring if current circle is the largest.
-2, change the color of the largest circle at the end, after all the circles have been made... else you might make multiple circles red.

```
    {
Random gen = new Random();
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int radius = 0;
double largestRadius = Math.max(radius);
Circle largestCircle = null;
Group root = new Group();
//prints out 30 circles
for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
    Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, radius);

    if (circle.getRadius() > largestRadius)
    {
        largestCircle = circle;
    }

    {
        radius = gen.nextInt(66) + 10; //generates random radius from 10 to 75
        x = gen.nextInt(600 - 2 * radius) + radius;
        y = gen.nextInt(400 - 2 * radius) + radius;
    }

    circle.setFill(null);
    circle.setStroke(Color.rgb(gen.nextInt(256), + gen.nextInt(256), gen.nextInt(256)));
    circle.setStrokeWidth(3);
    root.getChildren().add(circle);
}
largestCircle.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.3));
```

Comment: thank you so much! putting largestCircle at the end, and switching the == to > made all the difference

Comment: i really appreciate your help (:

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a good idea to initialize any `max` variable with a small number that is out of scope for your project. In this case, since radius can not be -1, I would do

```
double largestRadius = -1;
```

After this, it doesn't matter how big the radius can be, any radius bigger than -1 will change the largestRadius.

It looks to me like you are only missing one part and that is the if the newly created `circle` has a radius `> largestRadius`.

```
if(circle.getRadius() > largestRadius){
    largestCircle = circle;
    largestRadius = circle.getRadius();
}
```

After this, you have checked for if the new circle has a radius greater than AND you have checked if the new circle has a radius equal to. Keeping the `if` statement that you already have, you will always reference the newest circle with the `largestRadius`.

Comment: would it be largestRadius = circle.getRadius();?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot the `()`! Updated now.

Comment: i added in largestRadius = circle.getRadius(); and it filled in my biggest circle with the red. Thank you for your help I really really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the circle objects in an array.  Use a double (or whatever number type is appropriate for your random values) to track the high value with a simple comparison (is my current high value less than the new random value? if so, update high value) each time you generate a random value and create a circle of that size.

Once you have your 30 circles in your array simply loop through it until you find the first occurrence of your high value, when you find it make that circle whatever color.

```
Circle[] myCircles=new Circle[30];
double largestCircle;
for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
// determine your x,y, and radius here
   myCircles[i]=new Circle(x,y,radius);
   if(radius>largestCircle) largestCircle=radius;
}
```

Then to loop thru your myCircles and do things with each one

```
for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
   if(myCircles[i].getRadius()==largestCircle){
      // make myCircles[i] red here
   }
}
```